# Using the definition of a limit to prove that $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} (\bar{z} ^{2}+2)=2$

Tags: limits

For a given $\varepsilon>0$, we have to find ${\delta} >0$ such that $|\bar{z}^{2}+2-2|<\varepsilon$, whenever  $0<|z-0|<\delta$
so consider $|\bar{z}^{2}+2-2|=|\bar{z}^{2}|=|x^2-y^2-i2xy| \leq {|x|^2}+{|y|^2}+2|x||y|$.

How to proceed next to get relation in terms of $|z|$?

Comment: That doesn't look right, the limit should be $2$ not $2i+2$

Comment: ok. Then $|\bar{z}^2|=|x^2-y^2-i2xy| \leq {|x|^2}+{|y|^2}+2|x||y| $. After this how to proceed

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(z)=\overline z^2+2$, and $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then to show that $\lim\limits_{z\to0}(\overline z^2+2)=2$, we will determine $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|z|<\delta$ then $|f(z)-2|<\varepsilon$. Notice that $$|f(z)-2|=|\overline z^2|=|\overline z|^2=|z|^2<\delta^2$$ so choosing $\delta=\sqrt\varepsilon$ suffices.

Comment: $|\bar{z}^{2}|=|x^2-y^2-i2xy|$ and $|\bar z|^2=x^2+y^2$ so $|\bar{z}^{2}| \neq |\bar z|^2$ where  I am going wrong?

Comment: Note that $|\overline z^2|=|x^2-y^2-2ixy|=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^2}=x^2+y^2=|\overline z|^2$.